# How to move Gnome top bar to a secondary monitor

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors

I realize I could manage this by switching my secondary monitor to become primary one, but if I do then any and all games run at fullscreen will adopt the now primary monitor's resolution and that's unnaceptable for me.
So, I'm asking for a way to move GNOME's top bar to another monitor while retaining primary monitor status where it is.

Comment: Gnome 3, from all i know, will always display the the top panel on the primary screen. Your best bet might be looking for a gnome3 shell extension that overrides this, like [multi-monitors-add-on](https://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on). This one does not actually move it though, but duplicates it (you have the panel show on both screens). Might be possible to combine it with one that hides the top panel on the primary (not certain though).